# jQuery Draggable containment issue, cannot drag elements outside parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a very simple image manager, like so:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="draggable-images">
        <img class="images" src="image1.jpg" />
        <img class="images" src="image2.jpg" />
        <img class="images" src="image3.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="droppable-area>
    </div>

</div>
```

And jQuery to go with it:

```
        $( ".images" ).draggable({ containment: "#container" });
        $( "#droppable-area" ).droppable();
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#draggable-images {
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.images {
    z-index:10000;
}
```

Images are draggable, but they won't come out of their parent div, no matter what the containment is set to (even tried to set it to window).

Does anyone know how to make it work, or why it doesn't work?

I've set z-index high to make sure that's not the issue. I also tried making `#draggable-images` div without scrollbar, it didn't work either.

Seems to work like a charm on [jQuery's site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment), can't figure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('images').draggable({ appendTo: 'body' });
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Having scrollbars on the parent div might be a design need and shouldn't be considered the first option to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think this correct as of now. [jquery docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo) advise that *"The appendTo option only works when the helper option is set to not use the original element."*.
There is no clone in this case.

Comment: This works fine with `clone` helper and also with knockoutjs contexts for dropped item. Note that style of clone *might* be different than that of original element.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow-x:hidden` from `#draggable-images`. I too faced similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

- check your HTML, something's wrong with it
- remove the overflow styles of the parent
- z-index? needed?

http://jsfiddle.net/LRj9T/1/

Comment: Thanks. But I need parent div to have scrollbar - or is that simply not possible?

Comment: scrollbars means that you have a constrained container (defined width and height, overflow scroll) which means that whatever is in the box that exceeds, scroll is activated (and the contents cannot escape the parent). one work around is that when you start to scroll, you take the element out of the container while dragging.